# How to install VLC from the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, software-installation

I have just started using Ubuntu 13.10. I am trying to download VLC Media Player from the Ubuntu Software Center, but it shows only a **More Info** button. It shows no download option. How do I install it?

Comment: First Enable main and universe Repositories, Then try to install with software-center. if it's not working then open  Terminal and run apt-get update and apt-get install vlc

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could open Terminal and write: `sudo apt-get install vlc` and enter your password.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After everything finishes see whether you can install `vlc` from Ubuntu Software Center.

If above method doesn't work try this one:

Open "System Settings" and click on "Software and update".

Now enable all the options in "Ubuntu Software" tab (don't enable CD-ROM with Ubuntu option).

Now close the window. Now it asks for reloading software sources. Click Reload button. It starts downloading the repository information. Now go to Ubuntu Software Center and `vlc media player is now available for installing.